# Convert unknown type to object with property

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to parse JSON with TypeScript strict mode.

So basically I have value of `unknown` type. And I have something like

```
type Auth = {
  accessToken: string;
};
```

Value is likely to contain an object of this shape, but I want to have a converter which is both runtime and compile-time correct.

Here's code I came up with:

```
type Auth = {
  accessToken: string;
};

function convert(value: unknown): Auth {
  if (typeof value != "object") {
    throw new Error(`Unexpected type: ${typeof value}`);
  }
  if (value == null) {
    throw new Error("Unexpected value: null");
  }
  if (!("accessToken" in value)) {
    throw new Error("Missing property: accessToken");
  }
  if (typeof value.accessToken != "string") {
    throw new Error(`Unexpected type: ${typeof value.accessToken}`);
  }
  return value;
}
```

I expected this code to fully validate shape of unknown object, but I'm still getting the following error:

```
Type 'object & Record<"accessToken", unknown>' is not assignable to type 'Auth'.
  Types of property 'accessToken' are incompatible.
    Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)
```

I do understand that I can just cast `value` to `Auth` type, but that would prevent compiler to assist me if I'd add new field in the future but forget to add corresponding checks to the converter, so I would like to have a converter which works without overriding type system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution exploits a type predicate:

```
interface Auth {
  accessToken: string;
};

function isAuth(value: unknown): value is Auth {
  if (typeof value != "object") {
    throw new Error(`Unexpected type: ${typeof value}`);
  }
  if (value == null) {
    throw new Error("Unexpected value: null");
  }
  if (!("accessToken" in value)) {
    throw new Error("Missing property: accessToken");
  }
  if (typeof value.accessToken != "string") {
    throw new Error(`Unexpected type: ${typeof value.accessToken}`);
  }
  return true;
}



// then, say you have an unknown value and you want to check if it is an Auth
declare const x: unknown;

try {
  if(isAuth(x)) {
    // x type is refined as Auth in here
    x.accessToken;
  }
} catch(e) {
  // ...
}
```